# How can I collect all the text items in the below tags into a dictionary with name as key and year as value?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath

I've been trying to get the values of all the tags inside every movie tag(individually) into a dictionary with the 'name' - name of the movies as keys and year as value.

```
{"a": 2018 , "b":2017, "c":2017, "d".2016}
```

I'm a newbie to Stackoverflow and I hope I've provided all the details and met all the community 
Please find the minimum reproducible XML code here

```
<collection>
    <movie>
        <name>a</name>
        <year>2018</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <name>b</name>
        <year>2017</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <name>c</name>
        <year>2017</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <name>d</name>
        <year>2016</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <name></name>
        <year></year>
    </movie>
</collection>
```

I've tried multiple things using ElementTree and XPath, but I'm unable to fetch the values as mentioned above.
    If anything, I was able to fetch all the values in the name tag together and all the values in the year tag together - which is absolutely of no use and hence I'm not posting those codes here.
This is the outputI'm able to get...

```
[2018,2017,2017,2016]
[a,b,c,d]
```

But this is of no use if there are tags like the below one with incomplete values

```
<movie>
        <name>d</name>
        </year>
</movie>
<movie>
        <name></name>
        <year>2016</year>
</movie>
```